# How to fix my Spring Dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-ldap

My code compiles, but when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

```
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/*<my home directory info here>*/sts-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ldap-webservices/WEB-INF/classes/com/*<some domain here>*/ldap/services/UserServiceImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:63)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 31 more
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ldap-webservices] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/ldap-webservices] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'webservices'
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 21, 2014 5:46:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15833 ms
```

my mvn dependency:tree appears thus:

```
mvn dependency:tree[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.springframework.samples:ldap-webservices:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] org.springframework.samples:ldap-webservices:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core-tiger:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:provided
[INFO] \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7-b53:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 21 17:56:12 MST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/425M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The pom.xml looks like this (for right or wrong):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>ldap-webservices</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Springframework Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <!-- spring.ws.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring.ws.version -->
    <spring.ws.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    <context.path>ldap-webservices</context.path>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.9</logback.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-jpa.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa.version>

    <!-- Bean validation -->
    <validation.version>1.0.0.GA</validation.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

    <!-- servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version -->
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <jaxb-api.version>2.2.7</jaxb-api.version>
    <jaxb-impl.version>2.2.7-b53</jaxb-impl.version>

    <!-- Database access -->
    <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
    <ehcache.version>2.6.5</ehcache.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <!-- version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version -->
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring LDAP dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb-impl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ldap-webservices</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm trying to get past this issue to test my code.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that versions of the asm jar file appear in both the 'Spring 2.5 AOP' bundle, and the 'Hibernate 3.2 core' bundle.

By deleting the asm jar file from the Spring 2.5 AOP bundle the web app now starts and works fine.

Comment: I added the exclusion, but I still end up with spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar and of course this exists already in core, so I'm not sure how to fix my issues